# Number of characters compared during naive string matching

Tags: c, string, algorithm

I've been asked to find the number of characters that are compared during naive string matching. This was the function we were asked to implement:

```
// Count the number of characters compared while finding all occurences of the pattern in the given text
// Characters must be matched from left to right
int charactersCompared(char *pattern, char *text);
```

**So if the text is:"ABCEDF" and the pattern is: "EF" the number of characters I would compare using the brute force method would be 6** (comparing the first letter of text with the first letter of the pattern. If it does not match, compare the second letter of the text with the first letter of the pattern again.
If it matches, continue with the comparing the next letters of both text and pattern and so on)

After figuring out a logic with many example cases, I implemented the above function this way:

```
int charactersCompared(char *pattern, char *text)
{
    int i,j,comp=0; 
    int flag;

    for(i=0;text[i]!='\0';i++)    //iterating through all the letters of text
    {
        for(j=0;pattern[j]!='\0';j++)
        {
            comp++;             //to count one comparision. 
            if(text[i+j]==pattern[j])   //to check if similar to pattern
            {
                flag=1;          
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                if(flag==1)
                {
                    flag=0;
                    comp--;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //printf("VALUE OF C=%d\n",comp);
    return comp;
}
```

This works fine for the pair(ABCDEF,EF) (where the count is 6) but not for other test cases which include multiple occurrences of the pattern in text such as:
Text: ABCDEFGHEIEF
Pattern: EF

I'm supposed to get 14 comparisions whereas my output is 12. I don't understand where I am missing out.

If anyone can point out what is the faulty logic, it'd be of great help. Or if there is an easier way to do this, suggestions appreciated. The only constraint is that the method has to be a brute force method (i.e I can't really change the part where i compare each character of each string).

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that in worse case is `n(m-n+1)` , where `n` is length of pattern and `m` is length of text. Now, Since you only want to compute comparisons, there's no need for variable `flag`. Prefer [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle.

```
for(i=0;text[i]!='\0';i++)    //iterating through all the letters of text
{
    for(j=0;pattern[j]!='\0';j++)
    {
        comp++;             //to count one comparison. 
        if(text[i+j]==pattern[j])   //to check if similar to pattern
            continue;
        break;
     }
}
printf("VALUE OF C=%d\n",comp);
```

Comment: that does not work because comp is incremented extra number of times

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out why my program incremented comp extra number of times in the answer posted by @E.N.D . It was because the outer for loop continued until each letter in the text was not compared. But when we do it manually, it's only until the the number of letters remaining in text while comparision are equal to or more than the number of letters in pattern. So i changed a condition

```
int charactersCompared(char *pattern, char *text)
{
    int i,j,comp=0; //int flag;
    int lenp=length(pattern),lent=length(text);
    for(i=0;i<=lent-lenp;i++)
    {

        for(j=0;pattern[j]!='\0';j++)
        {
            comp++;
            if(text[i+j]==pattern[j])
            {
                continue;
            }
                break;
        }
    }
    //printf("VALUE OF C=%d\n",c);
    return comp;
}
```

This makes sense and works! Thanks for those who tried to answer!

Comment: This can be simplified into `comp++;

Comment: This can be simplified into `comp++; if (text[i+j] != pattern[j]) break;`. There is no need for the continue. Beside, the function name is `strlen()` and not `length()`.

Comment: well length was a function i had written to find the length of the string lol and thanks for pointing out the redundancy!

Comment: What if either or both string are empty? (Rhetorical.) (Consider what i represents in the for condition vs in its loop. Those things must be equal when the condition is true--because the loop's going to be executed. Then comment & instrument your code based on that. Then do the same sort of thing for every loop you ever write.) What if - underflows? (Rhetorical.) (Consider the possible inputs & outputs of every subexpression you ever write.)